# How to dynamically create a class with List property (c#)?

Tags: c#

I want to create dynamic a class that looks like this:

```
Class DynamicClass
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  List<string> ListData {get;set;}
}
```

i know to create class with simple object by Type Builder and PropertyBuilder but what about array or list objects?

in addidtion i want to create nested dynamic class like this:

```
Class Student
{
  int Id {get;set;}
}

Class Course
{
  int Id {get;set;}
  List<int> Students {get;set;}
}
```

how to do it?

Comment: Where do you want to use these dynamically created classes? Why aren't the classes coded directly in your project? What are you trying to do?

Comment: This just example, i goint to get this class details in text file and crate the class according to this. i need the ability to create this kind of classes

Comment: "but what about array or list objects?" - what about them? What specific problem are you having when you attempt to define a property of type `List<string>`?

Comment: if you mean creating code in design time, you can use T4 templates for generating code